# codeigniter pagination error 404

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have Admin controller in codeigniter

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) redirect('login');
    $this->load->library('pagination');

}

function index() {

    $offset = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $data['sitetitle'] = 'Výpis jobů';
    $data['listings'] = $this->Jobs_model->get_listings(0,$user_id = FALSE,$config['per_page'],$offset);
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2; 
    $config['base_url']     = base_url().'admin/';
    $config['total_rows']   = $this->db->count_all_results('jobs');


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->template->set('title', 'Domovská stránka');
    $this->template->load('template', 'site', $data);
}
```

}

and Jobs_model

```
function get_listings($category, $user_id = false, $limit = 0, $offset = 0) {

    $data = array();

    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $q = $this->db->get('jobs');

    if ($category) {
        $options = array('category' => $category);
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        $this->db->where('category', $category);
        $q = $this->db->get('jobs', $limit, $offset);
    }
    else {
        $query = $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        if ($user_id) $query = $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $q = $query->get('jobs',$limit, $offset);
    }

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    $q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

first page in paginatiom  obtain data, but links generating in pagination localhost/sitename/admin/3 produce 404 error. 
Where is problem in my script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/';
```

To:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/index/';
```

If you *need* the url to be like `admin/3`, you can use a [route](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) or [`_remap`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping).

Side note: consider using this to get your page number rather than the URI class:

```
function index($offset = 0) {
    // your code
}
```

It will do the same thing, but it's convenient to use the controller method arguments when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some change.

```
$config['base_url']=base_url().'admin/index';
```

change

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

check if you are using .htaccess or not. If you aren't, then $config['base_url'] in above should be

```
$config['base_url']=base_url().'index.php/admin/index';
```

Comment: I agree with @itachi

Answer (score 0):

If you get 404 error on codigniter paggination please check follwing things :

1 ) Check your controller it's index or somthing else if it's index then base_url should be :

`base_url().'admin/index/pages'` and if it's somethings else it should be :

`base_url().'admin/somethingelse/pages'`

2 ) Check 'uri_segment' by `$this->uri->segment(4)` so by this you got the page number then else will do the codiegniter.